# In cation analysis, can reagents of higher group precipitate lower group cations?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

My teacher told me that Al$^{3+}$ and Zn$^{2+}$ hydroxides are frequently precipitated together and that is why we have to be careful about the concentration of base (NH4OH) added.

Does this mean that the group reagent of a higher group (say, group 5) can precipitate a lower group cation (say, group 3)?

Comment: No, group reagent of a particular group can't react with other groups. However, if we talk about aluminum and zinc precipitating as hydroxide, yes it is correct and that the conc. of amm. hydroxide is of utmost importance. In schools, most of us finds that [zinc and aluminum are kept in separate groups](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67191/what-is-the-group-reagent-for-the-zero-group-ammonium-cation-in-inorganic-salt?rq=1), but it is in fact present in same group(III) but in different subdivisions (aluminum -  grp IIIA ; zinc - IIIB)

Comment: The reason for the subdivision is due to the fact some cations (iron, aluminum and chromium) are precipitated as hydroxides (NH4OH + NH4Cl). However, other cations (zinc, cobalt, manganese, nickel) are precipitated as sulfides (H2S + NH4OH) because their hydroxides hydrolyzes. Since, there is a common reagent (NH4OH), they are kept in same group but have two subdivisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, technically they can precipitate cations from lower groups.

However, while doing the analysis, due consideration is given to the concentration of the added reagent so that unwanted cations do not precipitate. For example, cations of group 2 and group 4 are both precipitated as sulfides.

On the other hand, since group 2 cations require lower concentration of $\ce{S^2-}$ to precipitate, $\ce{HCl}$ is added to group 2 reagent along with $\ce{H2S}$ to reduce $\ce{S^2-}$ (common ion effect). This provides $\ce{S^2-}$ just enough to precipitate group 2 cations and not group 4 cations.